# My supervisor wants me to quit the job

Tags: professionalism, communication, promotion

I work in a corporate with ~2000 employees.

We are a team of four developers, lead by my supervisor. I have been working  very hard for 4 years, including unpaid weekends and overtime. My work has always been praised and distinguished for high quality & user experience. My performance has been excellent for three years in a row, though I have never been promoted.

The problem is my direct supervisor.

1. She has never showed any respect or support to my extra effort for the company. Whenever I am staying after work she presents it as poor time management. Whenever I pay attention or respond in time to our "customers" (colleagues from other teams), she starts yelling about the deadlines of my other running tasks, though I have never missed a deadline since the start.
2. She tries to exclude me from all communication with other teams, sometimes I I get to know important news "accidentally" from phone calls or informal conversations with other colleagues.
3. She never ever supports me for technical issues. Whenever I have asked her in the past for anything technical, she starts yelling, telling that it's part of my job to investigate and fix unknown problems, or make decisions accordingly.
4. When my manager (her boss) assigned me as project manager for a side project--my initiative, she was overloading me with other tasks and then complained to the manager that I was getting tired and wasn't 100% dedicated to those tasks. Whenever a change request comes for development for this system, she assigned it to other team members, claiming that "someone else has to do the job, in case you quit the job".
5. She never ever praises me in front of other team members. I had a presentation of my developments to the stakeholders. They started applauding me in the middle of the presentation. She stopped them by literally saying "you are only applauding him because he is a guy (I am the only guy in the team), all of my developers are working equally, luckily I am the one who will evaluate their work".

I can go on forever. The thing is that I don't want to quit the job, I really like the company, the management and everything else. But, I feel very frustrated in my every day job. Also, I don't think she appreciates  the fact that I am trying to distinguish myself, making my promotion impossible.

Comment: A location tag would really help get answers specific to your situation.

Comment: have you talked to your boss's boss? i've heard - though never experienced or known directly - of people being held back like this. You need to escalate, to either HR or up your chain (skip your problematic boss)

Comment: Life lesson: NOBODY values you for doing unpaid work. In business and in private life, people value stuff according to what it costs them. You worked a weekend for free. It cost the company and the boss zero. How much is it valued by the boss and the company? Zero.

Comment: When she made her absolutely sexist comments ("you are only applauding him because he is a guy"), that was a point when you should have spoken up. ("I utterly reject your sexist comments. I am quite sure that these people here don't care my gender and would have applauded a woman equally". )

Answer (score 4):

Go to your boss's boss and request to be reassigned. Don't get into the problems, just say that you'd prefer to be on a different team. Preferably pick a team that knows and wants you and would support your request.

I assume your boss's boss is aware of the situation. You're probably not the only one dealing with this kind of unacceptable behavior from them.

If this person is actually yelling and/or verbally abusing you, that sounds a lot like harassment and you should document it on your own system (as in one you can access even if the company shuts you out of all of their sysyems) in case you ever need to pusue a claim against it (do the documenting even if you never ever ever intend to do anything).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, start taking contemporary notes of these incidents in case you need them for an unfair/constructive dismissal case. Emailing these notes to yourself is a good choice as they are timestamps so it's easier to prove that they are in fact contemporary. Witnesses would be a good option as well.

You can try going to your manager regarding this behaviour. You could try scheduling a meeting with both your manager and your supervisor and air your grievances face to face - that way you're stabbing her in the front, not the back.

It may be worthwhile seeing if there are any positions available in another team - your manager could help you with that.

Going to HR is an option but you have to remember that HR exists to protect the company from the employees. This is where contemporary notes and witnesses could pay dividends.

I would recommend polishing your CV and looking to move elsewhere - my personal experience is that change is good and often gives you a better chance to be promoted as well as a better paycheck than simply staying in the same company for several years. You've ready admitted that your career progression has stalled due to your vindictive supervisor and if nothing changes you are only going to suffer.

Comment: gosh just stop with the "HR exists to protect the company" it *honestly sounds like the company's best interest is to move OP to another team*. That would be protecting the company *and* helping the OP.

Comment: But... HR does only exist to protect the company....

Comment: @PeterK. No. It exists to help the company grow - which is what *every other part of the company is for too*. If your problem will, being solved, help the company grow, then HR is invested in helping you. Also, most folks who join HR *do so because they like helping people grow and flourish*. They *like* engaging and helping others.

Comment: @bharal you can believe that for as long as you want to. HR exists to keep the staff in line and pay them the least amount of money possible to get them to do their jobs.

Comment: @user1666620 Too cynical, but let's play with it - *And accounting exists to ensure minimal money flows back to the community.* **And IT exists to displace low-income workers (and, more recently, high income workers) of their jobs.** It still doesn't mean that IT won't help you when you have a software glitch, or accounting won't help sort out your payment issues - nor does it mean HR won't help you when you're being bullied or need training.

Comment: @bharal not in my experience. My experience says you do everything in your power to avoid dealing with HR except at hiring tone or exit time. Anything else is treacherous.

Comment: When you email yourself, email yourself on your private email address. You will not be the first, nor the last, to have some of his emails erased from your corporate email box. They can't do this to your hotmail, gmail or whatever you're using mailbox.

Comment: @bharal there are too many cases where this isn't true. Sorry if you live in a perfect world I am unaware of.